# form sent and route configuration

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use this source to send form when submit button is pressed and I have got into some problem I can't explain. My settings for routes.php is like this

```
route[default_controller]="welcome/login";
```

My Login class is like this

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
        {
        //....
        $this->load->view('welcome/login_view');            
        }
    public function confirm()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome/confirm_view');      
    }
}
```

This class is inside a file I leave in the "welcome" folder of "controller" folder.
Inside application/views/Welcome folder, I create a login_view.php with a form that looks like this

```
<?=form_open('welcome/confirm') ?>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

But after I press the submit button, I get this error.

Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, `route[default_controller]` is invalid PHP.

You're missing quotes... and a dollar symbol.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome/login";
```

Furthermore, if your directory is really *application/views/Welcome*...depending on what kind of machine your server is running on, you may need to capitalize the w in welcome when loading the view:

```
$this->load->view('Welcome/login_view');
```

CodeIgniter's core might strtolower() it, but in any case, be consistent; *NIX machines are case sensitive wrt directory names.